# Run specific program as administrator without UAC for specific group

Tags: windows, windows-10, uac

I need to run program as administrator for all users in some group.

Say that there is software name soft.exe and three users (ad-admin,user1-regular,user2-regular) in group userGroup.

I need that in every connection to one of the users in userGroup the software soft.exe will run as administrator(does not matter if as ad user or other administrator)

I tried to add task to run when each user enter his session but it work only for the admin user.for the other users the task's status was that I need elevation.

How can I run the task as admin for all users?

Comment: You need the admin right for what ? As you can monitor what the application do, and give special's right to the application. It will no longer need admin right after.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly in windows for an application to run as an administrator the user has to have administrator rights to the Computer running the application.

My advice would be to look at the application and look at what rights it requires and apply these to the user group in question.

If the application requires permissions you would not like to grant such as R/W to C:/windows I would advise looking at setting up application compatibility shims.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee461265(v=ws.10).aspx